# COVID-19 infection data when partitioning to communities

Tags: coronavirus, infection, infectious-diseases

Suppose we think of the disease in a certain country as follows.

We have a set of "communities" $C_1,\dots,C_k$ in the country where $k$ is some small constant, say $10$. Each individual is a member of exactly one of the communities.

The communities can be simply a partition of the entire population into groups of ages, races, cities, economical situations etc.

In each point in time there are $R_{i,j}$ for each $i,j\in[k]$ (which seems to be closely related to the infamous $R_0$). $R_{i,j}$ is the excepted amount of individuals in community $j$ that a sick individual from community $i$ is going to infect. Note that, not necessarily, $R_{i,j}=R_{j,i}$.

So, $R_{i,i}$ measures the infection inside the community, while $R_{i,j}$ for $i\neq j$ measures infections between different communities.

**I don't know if this is relevant for here, but do you know of some data or estimates of such parameters $R_{i,j}$ from somewhere in the world using any partition?**

Comment: While this is highly relevant, there are 2 problems: (1) Identifying transmission events is extremely hard (especially where the pandemic is out of control and track & trace is overwhelmed). (2) Demographic characteristics differ widely between countries and communities, so your estimates would only be valid locally. The closest thing to this I have seen is estimates for intra-household transmission (secondary attack rate) by demographic (e.g. [Bernal et al.](https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.08.19.20177188)).